# SELECT de restrição "AND" para a mesma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, select

Eu tenho um banco de dados que possui 3 tabelas, duas tabelas normais e uma tabela resultado de um relacionamento N pra N, por exemplo, imagine que as tabelas são "Carros", "Caracteristicas" e "carros_caracteristicas" para que seja possível utilizar a mesma característica em mais de um carro. Desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desta forma, a tabela carro_caracteristicas guarda a conexão dos carros com suas determinadas características pelo id do carro e o id da característica. A grande questão aqui é: Como eu faço um select em carros_caracteristicas afim de me retornar todos os carros que tem uma quantidade X de DETERMINADAS caracteristicas ou menos? (Pode ser que não tenha ficado clara a pergunta, então vou dar mais exemplos).

Vamos supor que esses são os dados das tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E eu preciso retornar apenas os carros que tem determinadas caracteristicas ou menos (os carros não podem ter mais caracteristicas do que que eu especificar, apenas menos), então vamos supor que eu quero um carro que tenha apenas as características "Teto solar" e "Gasolina" o único retorno que eu gostaria era que fosse "UNO" pois ele é o único carro que tem no máximo aquelas caracteristicas ou menos.

Por exemplo, se eu especificar "Direcao hidraulica" e "Gasolina" eu gostaria que retornasse apenas "GOL" e "UNO" pq eles tem no máximo essas duas ou menos. O HB20 por exemplo tambem tem as caracteristicas "Direcao hidraulica" e "Gasolina", mas ele tambem tem mais, por exemplo "Teto solar" portanto eu não gostaria que retornasse ele.

Eu já tentei resolver esse select de algumas formas, aqui estão:

Consulta 1:

```
select cc.id_cc, cc.id_carro from carros_caracteristicas as cc 
where cc.id_caracteristica in (select id_caracteristica from caracteristicas
                            where id_caracteristica = 3 OR
                                  id_caracteristica = 4)
```

Consulta 2:

```
SELECT cc.id_carro, (select count(id_caracteristica) from carros_caracteristicas
                       where id_carro = cc.id_carro) as totCaracteristicas
FROM carros_caracteristicas as cc
where (cc.id_caracteristica IN (1,2,3,4))
group by cc.id_carro                
having ((select count(id_caracteristica) from carros_caracteristicas
        where id_carro = cc.id_carro) <= 
       (SELECT COUNT(id_caracteristica) FROM caracteristicas
        WHERE id_caracteristica IN (1,2,3,4)))
order by cc.id_carro
```

Consuta 3 (Essa foi a que chegou mais perto mas ainda falha):

```
CREATE temp TABLE tmp_entrada(id_caracteristica integer)

INSERT INTO tmp_entrada VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO tmp_entrada VALUES(4);
select * from carros a
INNER JOIN carros_caracteristicas b ON b.id_carro = a.id_carro 
INNER JOIN tmp_entrada c ON c.id_caracteristica = b.id_caracteristica
WHERE (select COUNT(*) from carros_caracteristicas d 
       WHERE d.id_carro = a.id_carro) <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tmp_entrada);

DROP TABLE tmp_entrada
```

Um jeito de resolver meu problema seria transformar as caracteristicas em colunas na tabela carros, assim o select funcionaria desta forma

```
SELECT nome FROM carros WHERE 
(gasolina = 1 OR gasolina = 0) AND  
(dir_hidr = 1 OR dir_hidr = 0) AND 
banco_couro = 0 AND
teto_solar = 0 AND
diesel = 0;
```

Essa consulta me retornaria "GOL" e "UNO" com toda certeza, e isso resolve totalmente o meu problema, mas eu não acho que essa estrutura para esse banco está correta, tendo em vista que caso haja a necessidade de manutenção do banco para a adição de mais uma caracteristica eu terei que mexer na estrutura para adicionar novas colunas.

Comment: obs. essa coluna id_cc não precisa existir. A PK da tabela de relacionamento pode ser composta com as duas FK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra saber se a estrutura está correta, seria necessário saber o problema que está resolvendo com isso... mas não interfere na questão em si. Como comentei, apenas tiraria a PK incremental da tabela de relacionamento que não é necessária.

Você está querendo limitar a consulta pela quantidade máxima de características que o carro tem, normalmente isso é o contrário, o cliente escolhe no mínimo as características que o carro tem, mas tudo bem...

montei a estrutura no SQLFiddle e fiz a query, basicamente você deve selecionar todos os carros e suas características onde existam as características informadas e contar a quantidade de características que o carro tem, após isso, limitar pela quantidade:

```
select
c.id,
c.nome,
string_agg(ca.nome,', ') as caracteristicas,
count(ca.id) as qtd
from carros c 
inner join carros_caracteristicas cc on cc.carro_id = c.id
inner join caracteristicas ca on ca.id = cc.caracteristica_id
where not exists (select 1 from carros_caracteristicas x where x.carro_id = c.id and x.caracteristica_id not in (3,4))
group by c.id, c.nome
order by c.id;
```

Resultado:
[image: SQLFiddle]

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d34a4/20)

---

Alterada a condição para onde não existir os carros que não estão nas características informadas. Sendo assim não é mais necessário o filtro pela quantidade de características.

Comment: Rovann, muito obrigado por me ajudar, sua explicação abriu minha mente, mas mesmo assim ainda ocorre algumas falhas, quando por exemplo eu tento selecionar os carros com as caracteristicas 1,2,3 e 4 e limito a quantidade por 4 caracteristicas, o que acontece é que também é retornado S10, por que tem algumas das caracteristicas que foram informadas na consulta e no total tambem tem 4 características. Existe alguma forma de limitar a consulta somente as características que foram informadas? (A condição é: Se tem uma característica diferente das informadas, não inclui na lista)

Comment: Alterei a condição do where @Strxng, veja se lhe atende

Comment: Rovann funcionou perfeitamente, exatamente como eu queria, muito obrigado mesmo e peço desculpa pelo inconveniente, meu SQL é fraco (ainda hehehe)